# What adapter do I need to mount an old Minolta lens to a Canon EOS camera?

Tags: lens-mount, lens-adapter, canon-5d-mark-ii, minolta

I have an old Minolta Maxxum 7000 camera and 50mm lens (photos below). I would like to mount the lens on my Canon 5D Mark II. Is [this adapter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/400912519821) the one I need?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try asking the e-bay seller this question?
What type of mount is your lens?
On the e-bay page it says: `It allow you to use old Minolta MC/MD/SR mount lenses and macro accessories on all Canon EOS cameras, such as 350d, 400d, 30d, 20d, 10d, 5d....etc`

Comment: @Dragos With the photos of the lens, we should be able to help here as to saying which mount it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that would **not** be the correct adapter. The Maxxum 7000 was the first camera to use Minolta's new A-mount; quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minolta_Maxxum_7000):

> [The Maxxum 7000] introduced a new lens mount, the A system, breaking compatibility with its earlier manual-focus lenses in the MC and MD system.

Unfortunately, it's [not quite possible to make a glassless A to EF adapter](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22869/why-i-cant-find-an-a-mount-to-canon-ef-adapter), so you'd need a significantly more expensive adapter which contains glass.

Comment: note also that adapter with glass are likely to degrade the image quality...

Comment: And for a 50/1.7 lens, which I think the Minolta lens is, the OP would probably be better off just buying a 50mm Canon lens.

Comment: Also, if you *do* get one with glass, there still may be horrible gotchas, as I discovered here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/88617/whats-causing-this-white-smudge-in-the-middle-of-the-photo